# Using precompiled Handlebars templates in Ember 2 project

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I'm need to use some precompiled handlebars templates in my ember project along with my normal components and templates.  I've loaded the precompiled templates in my `ember-cli-build.js` file using `app.import()`. The precompiled templates are now showing up in the `Handlebars.templates` object,  which I mapped to `Ember.TEMPLATES["precompiled-template"]` in my Ember `app.js` file between the app declaration and app initialization.

When I check the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object, the precompiled templates are there as functions of the form `function(context, options)` unlike the other templates which are objects.

When I try to use the precompiled template nothing shows up.  Any thoughts?

Edit 1:  I'm talking about small ui templates not the whole route template, and I am willing to sacrifice bindings.

Comment: How did you compile the templates? Did you use the same version of ember-template-compiler.js as ember.js?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to use a helper to convert the handlebars templates to a string and creating a document fragment.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function helper(data/*, hash*/) {
  let precompiledTemplateFunction = Handlebars.templates[data[0]];
  return fragmentFromString(precompiledTemplateFunction());
}

function fragmentFromString(strHTML) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(helper);
```

usage: `{{helper 'precompiledTemplate'}}`

I'm importing the templates in the ember-cli-build.js file `app.import('vendor/path/to/precompiled/template');`

I haven't dealt with passing in attributes through the helper but I don't think it will be that hard.